# Convert constructor to method

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods, constructor, runtime

Due bad early design I have many controls (typeof (`MyControl`)) which are filled with data by calling constructor (functionality for filling is written in constructor not in separated method).
Now I need to update data in these controls, but I dont wanna dispose current instance of control and then create it again only for filling with new data. Due many controls I also dont wanna add any abstract method FillWithData into MyControl and then implement it in each child control.
My goal is to dynamically create method which will have the same body as Constructor(maybe without InitializeComponents() method - but it doesnt matter) and also the same parameters - then I will 'add' this new method into running instance of MyControl and fill this control with new data using this new method not with constructor.
It would be best, if its possible to make something like:

```
MyControlTextBox mct = new MyControlTextBox();



MethodBuilder newMethod = new MethodBuilder("newMethod");
newMethod.SetParameters(constructorParameters
newMethod.CreateBody(mct.getType().GetMethodBody());

mct.AddMethod(newMethod);
```

OR

```
mct.getType().GetMethod("methodWhichBodyIWannaChange") = newMethod;
```

and then

```
mct.getType().GetMethod("newMethod").Invoke(newData...);
```

is it possible to achieve something like this?
I can easily add any new virtual method or delegate into MyType and then if its possible change it with my new method and its "more real to do it" than adding new method into running instance. 
I was looking on MethodBuilder buts its quite complicated and I have to specify many other options and I am not sure if its capable to do what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered redesigning your code instead of going to horrible lengths to work round its current nasty state? The approach you're trying to use sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using OpCodes.Call to call the constructors? I know at least struct constructors can be invoked through OpCodes.Call.